# Using OkHttpClient on Wildfly causing an exception

Tags: java, ssl, retrofit, wildfly, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit 2.0.2 and OkHttp 3.2.0 to call Here Maps Rest API.

Running from a unit test, works perfectly, but when I try to run it on Wildfy, I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3.internal.Platform@68a0a06f, sslSocketFactory is class sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:187)
at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:151)
```

Can I solve this by modifying the configuration of Wildfly or is this a bug of OkHttp?

Comment: The upcoming OkHttp 3.3 has a feature that'll let you specify the Trust Manager manually rather than relying on reflection to fish it out of the SSLSocketFactory. You'll want that!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to wait for it, I need a quick solution, maybe I have to replace Retrofit to something else.

Comment: I tried the same with Unirest (http://unirest.io/) and works perfectly.

Comment: I am getting a similar issue, can you write an answer to this if you have solved this ?

Comment: I'm not using the OkHttp library anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue, looks this is a bug with the latest version of okhttp - 3.2.0
You can temporarily resolve it by downgrading your dependency to 3.0.1
Later migrate to a more stable version!

Maven dependency(Should solve) :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use this, because I was trying to use Retrofit which had OkHttp as a dependency, so I was not able to dowgrade it, because it was an indirect dependency.